# Multithreading hangs while reading standard output

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, vb.net-2010

I am trying to run a executable file with CreateNoWindow set to True and trying to read the standard output of the program and append it to list box. But the program hangs after some time. I am calling the process using a new thread.

I made a thread using Dim BG_thread as new thread(AddressOf StartApp). Then I defined StartApp function and inside the function I called a process using Process.start(app.exe), I set the startinfo to .createnowindow true, .useshellexecute false, .read standard output true. I created a while loop until the process is not exited. Inside the loop I read the standardoutput from the process using stream reader and added it to listbox by converting to string.

Comment: If it doesn't work then you did it wrong. We can't see what you did wrong if we can't see what you did. ALWAYS provide the relevant code.

Comment: Brother I made a thread using Dim BG_thread as new thread(AddressOf StartApp). Then I defined StartApp function and inside the function I called a process using Process.start(app.exe), I set the startinfo to .createnowindow true, .useshellexecute false, .read standard output true. I created a while loop until the process is not exited. Inside the loop I read the standardoutput from the process using stream reader and added it to listbox by converting to string

Comment: No one should need to read the comments to understand the question. Edit your question and include all the relevant information that you should have in the first place.